# Transfer Excel Pivot table to Access

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access-2010, pivot-table

I am currently working with a large set of data in excel, a pivot table of 35X42380. We needed to transfer this data into an access database, but doing this with a line by line macro was a nightmare, after 40 minutes of hanging I gave up.

I was wondering if there is a fast way to unpivot this table to transfer to Access.

the data resembles:

```
Zip     |   80   |    81   |    82   |

00501   | 1.0040 |  0.8963 |  0.7707 |

00544   | 1.0040 |  0.8963 |  0.7707 |

01001   | 0.6721 |  0.6614 |  0.6342 |

01002   | 0.6721 |  0.6614 |  0.6342 |
```

the big issue i'm having is that the zip column is A3:42380, the 35 ids are AM2:BU2, and the pivot table is AM3:BU42380

What I would like is:

Product |   Zip |   Factor

80   |  00501   |   1.0040

Forgive me in advance for my terrible formatting.

Also, I cannot easily change the format of the table, so avoiding that would be a plus.

Thanks,

Jay

Answer (score 0):

Pivot table is just grouped information that feeds from other data set. To find data set:
Click on pivot table 
You will see pivot table tools in the ribbon
Click on Analyze and Change Data source.
In Data source you will find location of table or range:
This is your un-pivoted table

To export excel sheet in Access:
Click on external data 
then select excel.
Select import the data into new table.
Select your workbook to import.

Comment: The sheet in excel isn't an actual pivot table. It is formatted like one, as seen above, but has no pivot table properties.

Answer (score 0):

You could also double click on grand total in pivot table to un-pivot it, but if its not pivot table you can't un-pivot it.